# Directly create sparse adjacency matrix - (matrix exceeds maxium array size preference)

Tags: matlab, memory

**Problem**

I am using an adjacency matrix in my algorithm, which worked fine as long as I tested it an small matrixes (3000) points. But my actual problem includes 167620 points and I would like to create an adjacency matrix for that problem.
But obviously due to the length I get the following problem:

```
Requested 167620x167620 (209.3GB) array exceeds maximum array size preference. Creation of arrays greater than this limit may take a
long time and cause MATLAB to become unresponsive.
```

I use the following code:

```
adjMat = zeros(size(NB_list_all,1));                      
for ind = 1:size(NB_list_all,1)
        adjMat(ind, nonzeros(NB_list_all(ind,2:end))) = 1; 
end
adjMatS=sparse(adjMat);                                    
G=digraph(adjMatS);                                        
E=table2array(G.Edges);
```

As you can see I basically need the Edge-list.

**Question**

Hence the question: Is there a way to directly compute a sparse adjacency matrix or is there a different way of getting the Edge list from an adjacency list ? 
My NB_list_all contains the points in column 1 and neighbours in column 2-5?

**EDIT**

My NB_list_all is an adajency list of the following form:

```
1   2   0
2   3   1
3   4   2
4   5   3
5   6   4
6   7   5
7   8   6
8   9   7
9   0   8
```

Column one the point indize and columns 2:5 the indizes of the points it is adjacent to. 0 if there is no neighbour. The matrix I want to create an Edge list for is 167620x5. I created the edge list before using the  `E=table2array(G.Edges);` graph function of matlab. Now I basically have two questions:

1. How would i create a sparse adjacency matrix from this adjacency list directly?
2. Is there an easier way of creating an edge list for this kind of adjacency list ?
   Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know all the indexes and values, and the end size of the matrix, a sparse matrix can be created with

```
adjMat = sparse(indexi,indexj,value,size1,size2);
```

in a single go. Actually, this is the preffered way of creating a sparse matrix.

---

Example:

You want the following matrix:

```
  0 1 1
  1 0 0
  0 0 1
```

you would build it as:

```
sparse([1 1 2 3], [2 3 1 3],[1 1 1 1],3,3)
```

---

with the example you gave:

```
NB_list_all=[
1   2   0
2   3   1
3   4   2
4   5   3
5   6   4
6   7   5
7   8   6
8   9   7
9   0   8];


% if the first index contains all numbers we can safely do this
% this is almost indexJ, but we have some zeroes that we dont like
indexJ=NB_list_all(:,2:end); 

% create indexI
indexI=repmat(1:size(indexJ,1),size(indexJ,2),1).';

% lets unroll the matrices
indexI=indexI(:);
indexJ=indexJ(:);
% lets remove the indexI and NB_list_all that have a zero somewhere, because those are not real
notzero=find(indexJ);
indexI=indexI(notzero);
indexJ=indexJ(notzero);

adjMat=sparse(indexI,indexJ,1,size(NB_list_all,1),size(NB_list_all,1));
```

Comment: Could you maybe explain this a bit more ? Which indexes exactly ? Thanks!

Comment: @KiW I dont understand. The indexes are where you want the values to be in. e.g.  you want adj(4,5) to be 3.4232, then indices are 4,5 and value is 3.4532. In your code you know where each values should be put in (your values are allways 1). I'd help you more, but its hard to do without the actually code and a [mcve]

Comment: @Ander_Biguri Well I think I slightly get (sorry was a long day). I have my indexes in NB_list_all in column 1 and all points these points are connected to the points in colum 2:5 (all indexes). Is there an easy way to combine this ? I am a bit slow atm - sorry

Comment: @KiW does the example help?

Comment: @Ander_Biguri not really to be honest. If you would create it from an adjacency list - could you show an example for that ? Something like `1 17 85 940 65` where point is 1 is the neighbour of 17 85 and so on ?

Comment: @KiW Its the same thing really. I'd like to help you more, but again, you didnt post a [mcve] so my hands are tied. with this information and your code you shoudl be really easily be able to create it directly.

Comment: What is mcce ? I can gladly provide more information if you tell me what you need exactly ( sorry I am not a programmer) :)

Comment: ahhh it didnt show the link ... it just showed [mcce] ... now i get it ;) sorry

Comment: @Ander_Biguri I edited the post - I hope this comes closer to a minmal, verifiable example.

Comment: @KiW a MCVE is something I can copy paste and run.

Comment: I hope this is now more in the form you imagined. My NB_list_all just contains 2 columns more containing furhter connections.

Comment: I hope you didnt give up on me. I am trying my best here :o

Comment: @KiW One: yes. Two: really? cant you just run the code and see it for yourself? Im trying to help but you can either google what (:) does in MATLAB or just run the code and see it for yourself, there is absolutely no need of me explaining it.

Comment: fair point I have been working 17 hours now ... cant think anymore. Thanks for your help!